# How to programmatically publish webservice to tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, cxf, jax-ws

I would like to publish a webservice **programmatically** to tomcat.
With e.g JAX-WS or Apache CXF
Similar to `Endpoint.publish(...)`.

```
//how to tell this tomcat?
Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:8080/SimpleService", serviceImpl);
//or better something like this:
Endpoint.publish("/SimpleService", serviceImpl);
```

Without need to use `web.xml` and/or `sun-jaxws.xml` (for each service)

**Question:**
Is there any known way to accomplish it (with JAX-WS or Apache CXF or ...)?

(I know there are similar questions already posted. But none of them really answers my question.)

Comment: I am not sure of your requirements. You want to deploy an application on tomcat(so you need web.xml) which programmatically publish a new endpoint to receive requests. Is it correct?

Comment: Tomcat manager web-app can be used to deploy a new web application (by calling the right url) (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Deploy_A_New_Application_from_a_Local_Path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an anwer to my own question.
I managed to make this work [**programmatically publish webservice to tomcat**] with help of Apache CXF.

Here is a simplified working example:

I subclassed a `CXFNonSpringServlet` and registered it in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>MyCXFServlet</servlet-name>
 <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
 <servlet-class>de.test.MyCXFServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>MyCXFServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/soap/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This is my subclassed `CXFNonSpringServlet`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Server;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ServerFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet;

public class MyCXFServlet extends CXFNonSpringServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void loadBus(ServletConfig sc) 
    {
        super.loadBus(sc);
        publishServices();
    }

    private void publishServices()
    {
        Set<Class> serviceInterfaces = new HashSet<>();
        serviceInterfaces.add(de.test.IUserService.class);
        serviceInterfaces.add(de.test.ILoginService.class);

        for (Class aSVCInterface : serviceInterfaces)
        {
            final String serviceName = aSVCInterface.getSimpleName();

            try
            {
                ReflectionServiceFactoryBean reflectionFactory = new ReflectionServiceFactoryBean(){
                    @Override
                    protected boolean isValidMethod(Method method)
                    {
                        boolean ret = super.isValidMethod(method);
                        WebMethod wm = method.getAnnotation(WebMethod.class);
                        if (wm != null && wm.exclude())
                            ret = false;
                        return ret;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String getServiceName() //Override for custom service name
                    {
                        return serviceName;
                    }

                };
                reflectionFactory.setServiceClass(aSVCInterface);

                Object proxiedServiceObject = Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{aSVCInterface}, new de.test.MyWebServiceInvocationHandler(aSVCInterface));

                ServerFactoryBean factory = new ServerFactoryBean(reflectionFactory);
                factory.setBus(getBus());
                factory.setServiceClass(aSVCInterface);
                factory.setServiceBean(proxiedServiceObject);
                factory.setAddress("/" + serviceName);
                Server svr = factory.create();    
                svr.getEndpoint().getInInterceptors().add(new de.test.MyServiceInterceptor());
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above Servlet will publish 2 simple interfaces as SOAP-WebService.
The implementation is dynamically (Proxies)

This is my `MyServiceInterceptor`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapMessage;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.AbstractSoapInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Endpoint;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Exchange;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.apache.cxf.service.Service;
import org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.BeanInvoker;
import org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.Invoker;

public class MyServiceInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor
{
    public MyServiceInterceptor() 
    {
        super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage p_message) throws Fault 
    {
        final Exchange exchange = p_message.getExchange();
        final Endpoint endpoint = exchange.get(Endpoint.class);
        final Service service = endpoint.getService();
        final Invoker invoker = service.getInvoker();

        if (invoker instanceof BeanInvoker)
        {
            BeanInvoker bi = (BeanInvoker)invoker;
            Object serviceObj = bi.getServiceObject(null);
            if (Proxy.isProxyClass(serviceObj.getClass()))
            {
                InvocationHandler ih = Proxy.getInvocationHandler(serviceObj);
                if (ih instanceof MyWebServiceInvocationHandler)
                {
                    MyWebServiceInvocationHandler h = (MyWebServiceInvocationHandler)ih;
                    h.setSoapMessage(p_message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The MyServiceInterceptor-Class is mainly used to inject the current SOAPMessage to `MyWebServiceInvocationHandler`.

My `MyWebServiceInvocationHandler` (I think, no code needed here) is responsible to invoke the real Service-Method. It just implements `InvocationHandler` and has a field for the Soap-Message (see `MyServiceInterceptor`). This is needed to get SOAPMessage-Details (like Header).

Hope this helps.
Cheers!